# 2 next frame previous frame in flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, button, frame

im a novice in AS3 it is possible to place 2  next frame button in a single AS3 code/frame this is my code pls help thanks

```
up1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNextFrame);

function gotoNextFrame(evt:Event){
    ,leftbody.nextFrame();
}
up1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoNextFrame);

function gotoNextFrame(evt:Event){
    ,leftbody.nextFrame();
}

down1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoPreviousFrame);

function gotoPreviousFrame(evt:Event){
    rightbody.prevFrame();

}
down2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, gotoPreviousFrame);

function gotoPreviousFrame(evt:Event){
    leftbody.prevFrame();

}
```

Comment: What issue you are facing? The code is perfectly fine

Comment: You might want to remove those extra commas just before `leftbody`.

Comment: @Sandeep - He can't have gotoNextFrame and gotoPreviousFrame defined twice in the same file/class.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two functions with the same name: 2 x `gotoPreviousFrame` and 2 x `gotoNextFrame`.

What you should do is either define separate functions for `up1`, `up2`, `down1` and `down2` click event. Or you can have a single callback function like this:

```
function buttonClicked(event:Event)
{
    if (event.target == up1) {
        // up1 was clicked)
    } else if (event.target == up2) {
        // up2 was clicked)
    } else if (event.target == down1) {
        // down1 was clicked)
    } else if (event.target == down2) {
        // down2 was clicked)
    }
}
```

Note that I am assuming that you have an `up2` button but instead of pasting its code, you pasted the code for `up1` twice. But if my assumption is not correct you can remove the `up2` part in my code.